# Draw graph from a certain point

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have following code (partial),

```
    phiCrit = 0.2*np.max(phiPart_t)
    time=[freqMeas * (x+1) for x in range(startFile,endFile+1,step)]
    SigUpper = np.zeros(Nt)
    SigLower = np.zeros(Nt)
    gammaDot_upper = np.zeros(Nt)
    gammaDot_lower = np.zeros(Nt)
    for k in range(0,Nt):
        charline = np.where(phiPart_t[:,k]>phiCrit)
        SigUpper[k] = Sig[np.max(charline)]
        SigLower[k] = Sig[np.min(charline)]
        gammaDot_upper[k]= gammaDot_t[np.max(charline),k]
        gammaDot_lower[k]=gammaDot_t[np.min(charline),k]
    plt.figure(7)
    plt.plot(time,np.abs(gammaDot_upper))
    plt.plot(time,np.abs(gammaDot_lower))
    #plt.yscale('log')
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.grid()
```

And I got this figure. I need to draw the x axis value starting from 100 while xaxis represent time.

[figure link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgfZ5.png)

Comment: if you just need to adjust the range of the x axis it should be: `pylab.xlim([100,your_value])`

Comment: @terencehill it should start from 100 but end limit is not fixed so it will be the last value of time. So I cannot define a fixed my_value for end part.

Comment: Just compute the max value of your x data using the max function. And maybe add some little more to have a better visualization.

Comment: @terencehill perfect it works. Thanks.

Comment: I'll post an answer so that this question will be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the function `pylab.xlim`to set the range of the x-axis.

you can use:

`pylab.xlim([100, max(time)])`